# Installation of SharePoint 2010 in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can i install Sharepoint 2010 in Windows 8 64 bit enterprise evaluation version?

I have the follwing Software IDEs

1)SharePoint 2010 Server edition
2)SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition
3)Windows 8 enterprise evaluation edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Sharepoint on Windows 8 is identical to that on Windows 7 installation.
Here's a link that I followed but for consumer preview though,
http://blogs.technet.com/b/spweb/archive/2012/03/21/running-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx

Comment: but while installing sp2010 using sql server 2008 i was not able to complete installation because there was no instance of 1033.what needs to be done?

Comment: I want to undo an incorrect negative vote but it doesn't let me unless you edit your answer. I thought the question was about sharepoint 2010 foundation.